# How to POST JSONObject to raw JSON in the body of a Retrofit request

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

I have a `JSONObject` and i need to pass  this `JSONObject` to server .Using `POST` method.

```
@POST("Sync_Status")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    Call<String> LookupSyncStatus(@Body String json, @Header("Authorization") String authToken);
```

and

```
public void SyncStatus(String requestbody, RetrofitCallback<String> retrofitCallback){
  
        Call<String> call = RetrofitClientInterface.getUserService().LookupSyncStatus(requestbody ,authkey);

        callForStatusJson(call, retrofitCallback);
```

Here is the request body containing data and checked it with Postman it's working fine. But Android does not pass the body. somehow body remains null

On passing data showing `400 error Bad Request`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you shouldn't pass the @Body parameter as a String. You should create an Object from the json String you're trying to POST and send that.
For example if you want to send this json:

```
{ "data":"something" }
```

You create an object

```
class Request() {
    String data;
}
```

then set the data to "something" and replace `@Body String json` with `@Body Request request`

Also, I recommend using a JSON Parsing library like Gson or Moshi so you can manipulate the data you receive a lot easier.